# How to allow no limits in accepted file types using input type=file?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

We use:

```
<input type="file"... />
```

to upload files.

There is "accept" attribute that we can use to set the particular file types. It means, when dialog opens we're not able to see all file types in some folder, but only ones specified by "accept" attribute.

How to overcome this limit that is to allow user to see all file types in selected folder in opened dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't use `accept` Attribute.It will show all files

[image]

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Damn one sec faster